# What criteria should be used for priority & change frequency in an XML sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap, change-frequency

On what criteria we can define the priority and change frequency in the sitemap.

Example if the website is a coupon/service website.

- The Home Page must be priority 1 Updated Daily
- Category Pages must be priority 1 Updated Daily
- Coupon Pages must be priority 0.5 Updated Weekly

Are the above settings correct?

Answer (score 2):

That seems fine, however search engines tend to ignore those settings. There may still be some services out there that will actually use those fields, but I don't know of any that still use them to advise crawl rates.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing about them that "must be." The only thing you must do is conform to the standard.

Whether these setting take any effect is not proven. [John Mueller at Google says](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-priority-change-frequency-xml-sitemap-20273.html) they don't have any effect on Google. Only timestamp is worth adding.